# Alerts from a log file with Powershell

Tags: tomcat, powershell

I would like to be alerted via email when the time it took to serve a page gets higher than 10 seconds. I can't use an external monitor as this is a closed system.

Here is a snippet from the log file I would like to watch.

```
02-Apr-2013 10:19:50 com.domain.service.core.actions.aaa.GetInfo handleAction
SEVERE: Post call to Widget Service Request WS
02-Apr-2013 10:19:50 com.domain.service.core.actions.aaa.GetInfo handleAction
SEVERE: ERROR: cannot attach result to XML doc
02-Apr-2013 10:19:50 org.apache.jsp.run _jspService
INFO: 35 |  |  | ffffHM6Ly8qLmhhcnJvdy5nb3YudWsv | page1 - time = 7905 ms
02-Apr-2013 10:19:55 org.apache.jsp.run _jspService
INFO: 35 |  |  | ODeeeeeeM6Ly8qLmhh45y4y55YudWsv | summary - time = 7800 ms
02-Apr-2013 10:19:56 org.apache.jsp.run _jspService
INFO: 35 |  |  | ODeeeeeeM6Ly8qLmhh45y4y55YudWsv | page2 - time = 3430 ms
02-Apr-2013 10:19:56 org.apache.jsp.run _jspService
INFO: 35 |  |  | ODeeeeeeM6Ly8qLmhh45y4y55YudWsv | page1 - time = 4210 ms
02-Apr-2013 10:19:56 org.apache.jsp.run _jspService
INFO: 35 |  |  | ODeeeeeeM6Ly8qLmhh45y4y55YudWsv | page3 - time = 4370 ms
02-Apr-2013 10:19:56 org.apache.jsp.run _jspService
INFO: 35 |  |  | ODeeeeeeM6Ly8qLmhh45y4y55YudWsv | page1 - time = 5708 ms
02-Apr-2013 10:19:56 com.domain.service.netServ.netServSTUFF createSession
INFO: creating session. token: xxxxxx
02-Apr-2013 10:19:56 com.domain.service.netServ.netServSTUFF createSession
INFO: creating session. encrypted token: xxxxxx
02-Apr-2013 10:19:56 com.domain.service.core.actions.user.CreateNetsolSession handleAction
INFO: netServ Token: GisLCpQwnMrMEWa5bHuQQw++
02-Apr-2013 10:19:57 org.apache.jsp.run _jspService
INFO: 35 |  |  | ODeeeeeeM6Ly8qLmhh45y4y55YudWsv | home - time = 14000 ms
```

What I would like emailed to me is the date and time of the threshold being met and the time its taking to load the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know how to read the log file. Are the times you're looking at the `02-Apr-2013 10:19:50` that appear at the beginning of some lines?

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. Yeh, It is a bit messy. The only lines I want to know about are starting with 02-Apr-2013 10:19:57 and ending ...| home - time = 14000 ms. Its a Tomcat log which seems to split things over two lines. The time = xxxx is what I need to monitor.

Answer (score 1):

If I got this correct your Tomcat log uses 2 lines purr event.

Here are some lines of PowerShell that will scan the entire log file once and send an email for every instance where the `home - time` is greater than 10 seconds.

```
$file = Get-Content tomcatlog.txt

$lines = $file.Count
for($i=0;$i-lt$lines;$i++){

#scaning the file for strings like  "home - time = #### ms"
if($file[$i] -like '*home - time = * ms'){

        #The date will be on the previous line
        $date = $file[$i-1].Substring(0,20)

        #Get the Milliseconds
        $time_index = $file[$i].LastIndexOf('=') + 2
        $time = [int]($file[$i].Substring($time_index).Replace(' ms',''))

        #Calculate the seconds
        $seconds = $time/1000

        "Line $i`: On $date the time is took to load was $sec seconds"

        if($seconds -ge 10){
            Send-MailMessage `
            -To 'Michael Bluth <Michale.Bluth@BluthCompany.com>' `
            -From 'Bob Loblaw <Bob.Loblaw@BobLoblaw.com>' `
            -Subject 'Tomcat' `
            -Body "Line $i`: On $date the time is took to load was $sec seconds" `
            -SmtpServer 'smtp.bobloblaw.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Now, from your question is sounds like you want to do some real time monitoring of this log file. So whenever a new event is added to the log, and the `home - time = 11000 ms` is greater than 10 seconds, send an email. If you just run this script once day you will get the duplicate emails from the previous day because the log file is the same.

Now if you created a new log file at the beginning of everyday and at the end of the day you ran the script, that would change things. So at the end of the script you can add a line to rename the log file `Rename-Item -Path C:\tomcatlog.txt -NewName "$(Get-Date -UFormat %y%m%d)_tomcatlog.txt"` and assuming the Tomcat log would get recreated by your server. That way each day you would only get emails from that day.

You can speed up the repeat times to every 12 hours, or every 6 hours, or every 1 hour. You'd accumulate a lot of files but it would be getting close to real time.

**Try 2**

```
$new_log_path = 'tomcatlog.txt'
$old_log_path = 'copy_tomcatlog.txt'

$lastwritetime = (Get-Item $new_log_path).LastWriteTime
while($lastwritetime -eq (Get-Item $new_log_path).LastWriteTime){
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

$newfile = Get-Content $new_log_path
$oldfile = Get-Content $old_log_path #Just a copy of the old original log file

#You calculate the difference of what was just written to the file
$updates = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $newfile -DifferenceObject $oldfile

#Copy the file so we can as reference of what already was parsed
Copy-Item -Path $new_log_path -Destination $old_log_path -Force

$len = $updates.count
for($i=0;$i-lt$len;$i++){
    #it would be $updates[$i].InputObject instead of $file[$i]
    ...
}
```

While the write time of the file doesn't change just sleep and check again in 100 milliseconds. When the write time does change figure out what was written to the file and parse only the new information that was written to it.

Comment: This is looking awesome and perfect for getting a better idea of whats going on. But to make it real time could your code sit within something like this: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b ?

Another way I thought to make it real time would be to mark the lines in the log with the word 'Checked'. Then within the code only check lines without 'Checked' and then when checked add the word. Wait no.. crap, this is Windows server and Tomcat will lock the file.. damn.

Comment: you can try getting the line number that the 'checked' line value is at, with that you can write it out to another file or an XML and simply parse the file starting at the last entry in the 'checked lines' file.

Comment: @ChristopherRanney that sounds like a cleaner way of implementing a 'real time' solution. How would I go about this?

Comment: I will get back to you with an answer using the same log file you provided. It will most likely require a scheduled job on the server, is that OK?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherRanney. Have you had a chance to look into this?

Comment: @jetgerbil, I was looking into it but I have some projects at work that started to chew into my StackOverflow time, I was able to make some significant progress before I was overwhelmed. I will post the script as an answer once I complete the 'already checked' section of the solution.